# How to ASP.NET Core 1.0.1 API HTTPS with Kestrel

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, iis-express, asp.net-core-1.0, kestrel-http-server

we want to implement an ASP.NET Core API (1.0.1) on an IIS Webserver (as proxy) which is runing on a Kestrel server.
Clients running agains the API should do this with an Certificate ussied by our company CA.
The user than should be authenticated by "Active Directory Client Certificate Authentication".

We are developing with Visual Studio 2015 (Update 3) on a developer client (not the web server).

After reading the trying to understand the machanisms I just tried a bit in code.
Sadly try and error does not helped much :)

Afterwards I tried to find some tutorials on the internet, but most of them are just covering parts of the solution and furthermore most of them are targeting ASP.NET 5.

**So whats my question?**

- Is there any good guide out there for my scenario?
- Is there any guide covering SSL with a real company CA (not just self created Developer CA Certs)
- Is it possible to enable SSL in IIS Express for debugging?
- How can I read a Client certificate in code; GetClientCertificateAsync() ALWAYS is null.
- Do I may have an understanding issue?:

Client --(SSL Cert)--> https://API (IIS --> Kestrel)

Do Kestrel need to use `"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Https": "1.0.1"` when I just want to authenticate the client cert via AD and read the certificate in my API to get the UPN?

**What have i tried?**

First I added `"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Https": "1.0.1",` to the project.json file.

In the Startup.cs file I added the following code into the `ConfigureServices` function:

```
 services.Configure<KestrelServerOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.ThreadCount = 4;
            options.UseConnectionLogging();

            HttpsConnectionFilterOptions https = new HttpsConnectionFilterOptions();
            https.ClientCertificateMode = ClientCertificateMode.AllowCertificate;
            https.ServerCertificate = GetCetificate();
            https.CheckCertificateRevocation = false;

            options.UseHttps(https);
        });
```

`GetCetificate()` retreives a certificate from the local store (**I think here I need a real server certificate with private key?**)

I am listening to the following ports:

`"server.urls": "http://localhost:6000;https://localhost:6001;"`

I let the default ValuesController untouched for testing.
When I run the API-Profile (NOT IIS Express) `http://localhost:6000/api/values` return the json data. When I request `https://localhost:6001/api/values` I got the following error:

> fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
>         ConnectionFilter.OnConnection System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (The server mode SSL must use a certificate with
>   the associated private key.) ---> System.NotSupportedException: The
>   server mode SSL must use a certificate with the associated private
>   key.    at
>   System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.AcquireServerCredentials(Byte[]&
>   thumbPrint)    at
>   System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.GenerateToken(Byte[] input, Int32
>   offset, Int32 count, Byte[]& output)    at
>   System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.NextMessage(Byte[] incoming, Int32
>   offset, Int32 count)    at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32
>   count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32
>   count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32
>   readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.PartialFrameCallback(AsyncProtocolRequest
>   asyncRequest)
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.InternalEndProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult
>   lazyResult)    at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.EndProcessAuthentication(IAsyncResult
>   result)    at
>   System.Net.Security.SslStream.EndAuthenticateAsServer(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult
>   iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean
>   requiresSynchronization)
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Https.HttpsConnectionFilter.d__3.MoveNext()
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>   ---> (Inner Exception #0) System.NotSupportedException: The server mode SSL must use a certificate with the associated private key.    at
>   System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.AcquireServerCredentials(Byte[]&
>   thumbPrint)    at
>   System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.GenerateToken(Byte[] input, Int32
>   offset, Int32 count, Byte[]& output)    at
>   System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.NextMessage(Byte[] incoming, Int32
>   offset, Int32 count)    at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32
>   count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32
>   count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32
>   readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.PartialFrameCallback(AsyncProtocolRequest
>   asyncRequest)
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.InternalEndProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult
>   lazyResult)    at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.EndProcessAuthentication(IAsyncResult
>   result)    at
>   System.Net.Security.SslStream.EndAuthenticateAsServer(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult
>   iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean
>   requiresSynchronization)
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Https.HttpsConnectionFilter.d__3.MoveNext()<---

Running IIS Express it seems to work (via http://localhost:31943/ and https://localhost:44317/ configured in the launchSettings.json)
But nevertheless I still can't get the ClientCertificate.

Comment: If you plan to run Kestrel behind IIS/Express you can remove all of the HTTPS settings from kestrel, that's managed by IIS and it forwards to kestrel over HTTP. As for the client cert, enable that setting in IIS and it will be forwarded to Kestrel.